# How can I open a ListPreference dialog from an option menu in Android

Tags: android, listpreference, optionmenu

I would like to open a ListPreference popup from an option Menu of my app.

For now I manage to do that by opening a PreferenceActivity & fragment screen which automatically opens the ListPreference popup, but I once I changed the ListPreference value or cancel the popup I can see still see the Preference Activity screen.
Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried adding adding a call to the activity onBackPressed method in the ListPreference OnPreferenceChangeListener, but it only works when the value is changed, not when the cancel button is pressed.

Please let me know if you know a better way to do that.
Thanks

Comment: I think you want to open Activity as Dialogue .. if i am right than u can set theme for preference activity as android:theme="@style/Theme.UserDialog" In ur android Manifest.

Comment: I don't want to open an activity as a dialog. I want to open a list preference from a standard activity and not from a Preference fragment